# Accessing the Oracle cloud with MySQL workbench

Tags: oracle, mysql-workbench

I want to connect the Oracle instances with MySQL workbench.
I do not know if it's possible or not.

Answer (score 1):

The correct tool to use for this is Oracle SQL Developer.

You can download it [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html).

A guide to setting up a connection to a cloud DB is [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/paas/accessdbinstance/accessdbinstance.html).

Comment: Can't we access Oracle server with the MySQL workbench.

Answer (score 0):

not all so bad - 
https://cloud.oracle.com/en_US/mysql/features, 
Phil - MySQL is also Oracle

[How to do](https://youtu.be/8nolEt0-XXs)
(video)

Comment: I am not going to connect mysql cloud service. I have to connect oracle cloud linux compute instance from MySQL workbench which is in client windows system.

Comment: in this case - other answer, MySQL Workbench - for MySQL, SQL Developer for Oracle

Comment: why do you HAVE to connect to an Oracle db with MySQL workbench?